# NuGet Centrally Manager Packages - NU1604 Error on build with dotnet build

Tags: c#, .net, nuget

I am trying out the Centrally Managed Packages feature in NuGet and keep getting the following error in all of my projects:

```
NU1604: Project dependency Ardalis.SmartEnum does not contain an inclusive lower bound. Include a lower bound in the dependency version to ensure consistent restore results.
```

I have the following defined in the `.csproj`

```xml
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageReference Include="Ardalis.SmartEnum" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

and the following `Directory.Build.props` defined in the root folder beside my `.sln` file

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
        <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
        <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
        <TreatWarningsAsErrors>true</TreatWarningsAsErrors>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageVersion Include="Ardalis.SmartEnum" Version="2.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

An interesting thing is that I am able to get the project to build in Rider, but not with the `dotnet build` command. Both when running in the root folder and in the project folder. I have tried `dotnet clean` on both the solution and the project.

For clarity the file structure is:

```
root/
├─ Directory.Build.props
├─ MySolution.sln
├─ src/
│  ├─ ProjectFolder/
│  │  ├─ ProjectFolder.csproj
```

What am I missing here?

Comment: What is the output of `dotnet --version`?

Comment: For reference the output of `dotnet --version` is `7.0.100`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was missing a key piece of information.

Centrally managed packages **should not** be defined in `Directory.Build.props`.

They should be defined in `Directory.Packages.props`

Directory.Packages.props

```xml
<Project>
    <PropertyGroup>
        <ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>true</ManagePackageVersionsCentrally>
    </PropertyGroup>

    <ItemGroup>
        <PackageVersion Include="Ardalis.SmartEnum" Version="2.1.0" />
    </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```